# Where is commutativity of $b$ needed?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have a question about the following proof:

[image]

If $e^{ia}-e^{i\lambda}=(a-\lambda)be^{i\lambda}$ and $(a-\lambda)$ is not invertible then $(a-\lambda)x$ is not invertible for all $x$. Why "since $b$  commutes with $a$"?

Comment: In a noncommutative algebra, $xy$ invertible does not imply that $x$ is invertible (it only implies that $x$ has a right inverse).

Comment: @ChrisL Thank you for your comment. Why did you not post it as an answer? If you think it's too short, why not elaborate with an example? I'm happy to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example where this happens is given by the unilateral shift in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. If 
$$
S(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(0,a_1,a_2,\ldots),
$$
then $S^*S$ is the identity, so invertible. But
$$
SS^*(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(0,a_2,a_3,\ldots)
$$
so not invertible (it has kernel).

There are C$^*$-algebras where it is true that $xy$ invertible implies $yx$ invertible. This happens for example in the presence of a faithful tracial functional, i.e. a positive functional $f$ such that $f(ab)=f(ba)$ for all $a,b$ (tracial) and that $f(a^*a)=0$ implies $a=0$ (faithful).

Examples of C$^*$-algebras with this property are all finite-dimensional ones, and more. Concretely, any residually finite dimensional C$^*$-algebra has a faithful tracial state (proven by Choi in the 80s). Also, all II$_1$-factors have a faithful trace.